# Как в gitlab ci log скрыть вводимые команды (echo off)?

Tags: bash, gitlab, gitlab-ci

Сейчас в логах сборок вывод примерно такой (bash):

```
...
$ echo "Finish recompile objects"
Finish recompile objects
$ echo "BUILD - OK"
BUILD - OK
...
```

То есть при просмотре выводятся вводимые команды и их результат. Есть ли возможность скрыть команды и оставить только вывод?

```
...
Finish recompile objects
BUILD - OK
...
```

В cmd есть режим echo off, вот хотелось бы активировать такой же.

Буду благодарен за любые идеи :)

Comment: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/4645

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как правильно направил aleksandr barakin в комментариях, решение заключается в многострочном скрипте с использованием | ([literal](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/script.html#split-long-commands))

```
myjob:
  script:
  - |
    # printing the job information
    echo --------------------------
    echo Building ${CI_COMMIT_SHA}
    echo --------------------------
```

На выводе в логе будет следующий результат:

```
(...)
$ # printing the job information # collapsed multi-line command
--------------------------
Building 629fcab9e39f8564cb2a0d1a7f104e2312a22288
--------------------------
(...)
```

В итоге, вводимые команды не отображаются, кроме первой, а вывод от них корректно отображается.

Больше вариантов решения можно увидеть в этом обсуждении - https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/4645